# every principal factor of a finite soluble group is elementary abelian.

Tags: finite-groups

every principal factor of a finite soluble group is elementary abelian.

I am a little confused in a lot of definitions and I stuck in this exercise,this is so great if you just give me hints that I could be in right way,I really appreciate,thank you.

Comment: by principal factor, you mean $G/M$ where $M$ is maximal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that principal$\equiv$chief? Are you familiar with the fact that the chief factors are always *characteristically simple*, that is, they have no non-identity proper characteristic subgroups? In particular, a chief factor is a direct product of isomorphic *simple* groups. And in case of solvable groups this boils down to a direct product of cyclic groups of the same prime $p$.